# Initial Value Problem $dy/dx = (y+1)^{1/3}$

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

Consider the differential equation $$\frac{dy}{dx} = (y+1)^{1/3}$$

(a) State the region of the $xy$-plane in which the conditions of the existence and uniqueness theorem are satisfied (using any appropriate theorem).

(b) Let $S$ be the region of the $xy$-plane where the conditions of the existence and uniqueness theorem are NOT satisfied. State whether the given equation with the initial condition $y(x_0)=y_0$, where $(x_0, y_0)$ is an element of $S$, has a solution.

(c) solve this equation

(d) Using the result of (c), find whether the given equation with the initial condition $y(x_0) = y_0$, where $(x_0, y_0)$ is an element of $S$, has a unique solution.

Struggling massively with this question. Currently studying initial value problems but haven't been able to come across any text or vid explaining the technique to approach this. Would very much appreciate any help.

I can only assume for part (a) the region of the xy plane is -infinity < x < infinity. And -1 < y < infinity.

For (b) I don't know the technical method of approaching this question even after reading through a differential equations textbook because it was explained it riddles.

For (c) i arrived at y = [[(2/3)(x+c)]^(3/2)]-1. Don't know if evaluating it further is necessary or not?

For (d) again I used a book which didn't explain the steps to doing this

Answer (score 1):

I'll help you with $c$ but you have to tell us what your thoughts are regarding the rest of the question-the solution will help with $d$.

Using separation of variables,

$$ \int (y+1)^{-\frac{1}{3}}dy = \int \ dx $$

$$ \frac{3}{2} (y+1)^{\frac{2}{3}} = x + c$$

Comment: I can only assume for part (a) the region of the xy plane is -infinity<x<infinity. And -1<y<infinity.

For (b) I don't know the technical method of approaching this question even after reading through a differential equations textbook because it was explained it riddles.

For (c) i arrived at the same equation which I evaluated to y = [[(2/3)(x+c)]^(3/2)]-1. Don't know if evaluating it further is necessary or not?

For (d) again I used a book which didn't explain the steps to doing this.

Comment: I think it will be really useful to add the above information to your question so others can see your efforts and assist you in answering them.

Comment: Thanks John, have edited the question

Answer (score 0):

You probably have to use Picard-Lindelöf. The function is not Lipschitz around $y = -1$.

Comment: Please expand your answer, at least give some pointers/hints.

Answer (score 0):

For part (a), you're on the right track;  note, however, that the equation is just as well-defined for $y < -1$ as it is for $y > -1$.  @crankk's suggestion to apply the Picard-Lindelöf Theorem would be the most rigorous way of showing this.

For part (b), I'm not sure that there's a "technical method" to address the question.  However, I will tell you that the answer is "yes", and that there's a fairly obvious solution to the above equation that goes through $(x_0, y_0) = (x, -1)$ for arbitrary $x$;  finding and exhibiting this solution should be sufficient, I would think, for a definitive answer to the question.

Comment: Could you explain why the answer is yes to (b) please?

Comment: @MWTDeeks:  Is this for self-study, or is this a homework problem?  if the latter, I'd rather not give you the answer outright.  The only other hint I can give without giving the game away is that the function is really, really simple;  maybe you could try thinking of really simple functions for $y(x)$ and plugging them in to the equation to see if they work.

Comment: Hi Michael, this is for self study. I assume you mean subbing in something like y(x) = -1?

Comment: Yup, that's a valid solution that goes through the point $(x_0, -1)$ for any value of $x_0$.  So a solution exists for any point in the region $S$.  The general solutions (you should now show) are also all tangent to the region $S$, which means that solutions passing through the points in $S$ are not in fact unique.